# C++ - thread_local vector causes crash on join() on MinGW

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, mingw

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

thread_local vector<int> v;

void foo(int n) 
{  
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        v.push_back(i);
}

int main() 
{
    vector<thread> thread_array;
    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        thread_array.push_back(thread(foo,100));
    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        thread_array.at(i).join();
    return 0;
}
```

This program crashes for me after reaching the second for loop (the joining one), but not always. Sometimes it exits just fine, sometimes it crashes.

What could be causing this?

Comment: There are a number of known issues with using `thread_local` for non-trivial objects in MinGW. [Here's one.](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/)

Comment: Note: this issue is _still_ not fixed as of MinGW 11.2 (64bit).