# A thread local variable has unexpected value during destruction

Tags: c++, thread-local-storage

I have the following code written using C++17 standard:

```cpp
std::mutex mutex{};

struct Test {
  ~Test() {
    {
      std::lock_guard lock{mutex};
      std::cout << "~Test() = " << a << std::endl;
    }
    
    delete a;
  }

  int *a;
};

thread_local Test test{};

void Foo(int i) {
  test.a = new int{i};
  std::lock_guard lock{mutex};
  std::cout << "Thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " value: " << test.a
            << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  threads.reserve(7);
  for (std::size_t i{1}; i < 8; ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back(Foo, i);
  }

  Foo(0);

  for (auto &thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
  }
  threads.clear();

  return 0;
}
```

I just create some threads and initialize thread local variable **test** by allocating new memory. Of course I should not forget to free the memory allocated before; and I do so in a destructor of the thread local object (`Test::~Test()`). But I gain what is not expected: when the destructor of any thread start executing it doesn't have the same value of pointer that was allocated in `Foo()`, therefore, in the end, I get an error.

Possible output of this program (debug):

```
Thread: 4 value: 0x14ca4b81ae0
Thread: 2 value: 0x14ca4b84f80
~Test() thread: 4 value: 0x211bbc59c792f
Thread: 3 value: 0x14ca4b847a0
Signal: SIGTRAP (Trace/breakpoint trap)
Signal: ? (Unknown signal)
```

Possible output of this program (non-debug):

```
Thread: 2 value: 0x224eb8926c0
Thread: 3 value: 0x224eb892820
~Test() thread: 2 value: 0x224eb8926c0
Thread: 1 value: 0x224eba77670
~Test() thread: 3 value: 0x224eb892820
Thread: 6 value: 0x224eba77650
~Test() thread: 6 value: 0x224eba77650
Thread: 5 value: 0x224eba776a0
~Test() thread: 5 value: 0x224eba776a0
Thread: 4 value: 0x224eba77680
~Test() thread: 4 value: 0x224eba77680
Thread: 7 value: 0x224eba77700
~Test() thread: 7 value: 0x224eba77700
Thread: 8 value: 0x224eba77690
~Test() thread: 8 value: 0x224eba77690
~Test() thread: 1 value: 0x224eba77670

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What do I do wrong with the thread local variable?

### **UPDATE**

The problem occurs when I build with MinGW (w64 9.0), g++, CMake (build types: Release and Debug). But I've tried to use MSVC (x86) and everything works fine.

Comment: One thing that concerns me is that when the main thread ends, I think the mutex might be destroyed before its `test`. When that `Test` is destroyed it will then try to lock a destroyed mutex. I'm not sure if the main thread's `threadlocal` are destroyed before global objects or according to normal static destruction (bottom of the translation up).

Comment: Please share the compiler version and build flags you are using.

Comment: My immediate suspicion is that this is a variant of the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) (or [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)), except obviously it's not the SAME either.  I'm always suspicious of non-POD types being global variables.

Comment: Works for me - live clang, gcc, msvc - https://godbolt.org/z/q6rhcrf8E

Comment: @François Andrieux, ohhh, the mutex must be defined before `struct Test` hence it is defined before `thread_local Test test`, so I think there is no problem.

Build with CMake using CLion (MinGW).

Comment: "The destruction of all constructed objects with thread storage duration within that thread strongly happens before destroying any object with static storage duration." So I don't think that's it.

Comment: Does your debugger support "watchpoints" to detect when a region of memory changes value?

Comment: @pm100 That is 1) totally irrelevant for the core issue here and 2) wrong, since he loads seven elements, or am I missing something? The provided code seems ok to me, although I'd always initialize thread_local variables explicitly in each thread. But the way it's done here is valid standard C++ IMO. Must be a compiler bug.

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50008553/3740047) and [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/) problem. It is apparently fixed in [gcc 12.1](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/7fc0f78c3f43af1967cb7b1ee8f4947f3b890aa2).

Comment: Updated to gcc 12.1 and, unfortunately, I have the same problem. Also, I tried to use clang: the same error occurs.