# Implementation of Stackful Coroutine in C++

Tags: c++, exception, assembly, x86-64, coroutine

Now I am trying to implement stackful coroutine in C++17 on Windows x64 OS, but, unfortunately, I have encountered the problem: I can't throw exception in my coroutine, if I do so, the program is immediately terminated with a bad exit code.

**Implementation**
At the begining, I allocate a stack for a new coroutine, the code looks something like that:

```cpp
void* Allocate() {
  static constexpr std::size_t kStackSize{524'288};
  auto new_stack{::operator new(kStackSize)};
  return static_cast<std::byte *>(new_stack) + kStackSize;
}
```

The next step is setting a trampoline function on the recently allocated stack. The code is written using MASM, since I utilize MVSC (I would like to use GCC and NASM but I have the problem with `thread_local` variables, see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605969/a-thread-local-variable-has-unexpected-value-during-destruction), if it is interesting):

```
SetTrampoline PROC
    mov rax, rsp ; saves the current stack pointer
    mov rsp, [rcx] ; sets the new stack pointer

    sub rsp, 20h ; shadow stack
    push rdx ; saves the function pointer

    ; place for nonvolatile registers
    sub rsp, 0e0h

    mov [rcx], rsp ; saves the moved stack pointer
    mov rsp, rax ; returns the initial stack pointer

    ret
SetTrampoline ENDP
```

Then I switch machine context with this assembly function (I read this [calling convetion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170)):

```
SwitchContext PROC
    ; saves all nonvolatile registers to the caller stack
    push rbx
    push rbp
    push rdi
    push rsi
    push r12
    push r13
    push r14
    push r15

    sub rsp, 10h
    movdqu [rsp], xmm6

    ; ... pushes xmm7 - xmm14 in here, removed for brevity

    sub rsp, 10h
    movdqu [rsp], xmm15

    mov [rdx], rsp ; saves the caller stack pointer

SwitchContextFinally PROC
    mov rsp, [rcx] ; sets the callee stack pointer

    ; takes out the callee registers
    movdqu xmm15, [rsp]
    add rsp, 10h

    ; ... pops xmm7 - xmm14 in here, removed for brevity    
  
    movdqu xmm6, [rsp]
    add rsp, 10h

    pop r15
    pop r14
    pop r13
    pop r12
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    pop rbp
    pop rbx

    ret
SwitchContextFinally ENDP
SwitchContext ENDP
```

**Problem**
Inside the trampoline I just invoke any passed function and within these functions I can't throw exceptions and catch them instantly in the same fucntion. What have I done wrong? Is it possible to throw exceptions in my case? Should I have shadow stack in `SetTrampoline`?

Also, I guarantee that the exception thrown don't go outside the trampoline function.

Comment: You didn't update the system bookkeeping related to the stack, so the system assumes that the process has become corrupted (possibly by malware) and terminates it. Use fibers for stack switching.