# thread_local unordered_map crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, unordered-map

Windows user here, I've created an minimum reproducible example of what I believe may be the cause of my program crashing.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>


thread_local std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t> repetition_table;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    repetition_table.insert(std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> (0ULL, 0ULL));
    std::cout << "Hi\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I am using g++ version 9.2.0. When I compile and run the above program, it crashes and exits with exit code: -1073741819. I suspect this is an OS related issue as running it in an online UNIX environment seems to work fine. Does anyone know the cause of this issue?

I tried compiling and running. I expect it to insert 0,0 into the repetition table and print Hi, and then return with exit code 0. It prints Hi and returns with the exit code corresponding to Access Violation Error.

Comment: fyi `-1073741819` is `0xC0000005` which is access violation on Windows.

Comment: This [appears to work as expected](https://godbolt.org/z/hdzefezfT) with g++ 9.2.0

Comment: This may be the issue if you are using MinGW (it's still open) - https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/2519  And also (again still open) much simpler example - https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/

Comment: See also [C++ - thread_local vector causes crash on join() on MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008553/c-thread-local-vector-causes-crash-on-join-on-mingw)